# Get property name in Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

ASP.NET Core introduced custom tag helpers which can be used in views like this:

```
<country-select value="CountryCode"  />
```

However, I don't understand how can I get model property name in my classes:

```
public class CountrySelectTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
       ...
       // Should return property name, which is "CountryCode" in the above example
       var propertyName = ???();  
       base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

In the previous version I was able to do this by using `ModelMetadata`:

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
var property = metadata.PropertyName; // return "CountryCode"
```

How can I do the same in the new `ASP.NET` tag helpers?

Comment: Why don't you use `Value` property?

Answer (score 6):

In order to get property name, you should use `ModelExpression` in your class instead:

```
public class CountrySelectTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var propertyName = For.Metadata.PropertyName;
        var value = For.Model as string;

        ...

        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Dont forget to add "for" attribute to the TagHelper in Razor view.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a string via the tag helper attribute.

```
 <country-select value="@Model.CountryCode"  />
```

The `Value` property will be populated by Razor with the value of `Model.CountryCode` by prepending `@`. So you get the value directly without the need to pass the name of a model property and accessing that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you got what you wanted. If you are looking to pass the complete model from view to the custom tag helper, this is how i do it.

You can pass in your current model from the view using any custom attributes. See the example below.
Assuming your model is `Country`

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

}
```

Now declare a property in your custom tag helper of the same type.

```
public Country CountryModel { get; set; }
```

Your controller would look something like this

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var country= new Country
    {
        Name = "United States",
        Code = "USA"
    };

    return View("Generic", country);
}
```

In this setup, to access your model inside the taghelper, just pass it in like any other custom attribute/property

Your view should now look like something like this

```
<country-select country-model="@Model"></country-select>
```

You can receive it in your tag helper like any other class property

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
   ...
   // Should return property name, which is "CountryCode" in the above example
   var propertyName = CountryModel.Name;  
   base.Process(context, output);
}
```

Happy coding!